# Conditionally Rendering Material UI Elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to render Material UI Elements like **MenuItem** of a AppBar Conditionally if some conditions are true. In my example menu items should only be rendered for specific users. But it doesnt work like the way it would work with normal html in react.

```
{context.token && context.userRole === "USER" && (
  <MenuItem key="submission" onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
    <Typography textAlign="center">Submission</Typography>
  </MenuItem>
)}
{context.token && context.userRole === "JUDGE" && (
  <MenuItem key="submissions" onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
    <Typography textAlign="center">Submissions</Typography>
  </MenuItem>
)}
```

Its rendering this Items all the time anyways and seems to ignoring the conditions.

The full code:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthContext from "../context/auth-context.js";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Menu from "@mui/material/Menu";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import Avatar from "@mui/material/Avatar";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Tooltip from "@mui/material/Tooltip";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import ComputerIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Computer";

const ResponsiveAppBar = (props) => {
  const pages = ["Conditions", "Winner", "Submission", "Submissions", "Login"];
  const settings = ["Profile", "Settings", "Logout"];

  const [anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = React.useState(null);
  const [anchorElUser, setAnchorElUser] = React.useState(null);

  const handleOpenNavMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleOpenUserMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorElUser(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleCloseNavMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElNav(null);
  };

  const handleCloseUserMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Consumer>
      {(context) => (
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Container maxWidth="xl">
            <Toolbar disableGutters>
              <Typography
                variant="h6"
                noWrap
                component="div"
                sx={{ mr: 2, display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" } }}
              >
                <ComputerIcon />
              </Typography>

              <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: "flex", md: "none" } }}>
                <IconButton
                  size="large"
                  aria-label="account of current user"
                  aria-controls="menu-appbar"
                  aria-haspopup="true"
                  onClick={handleOpenNavMenu}
                  color="inherit"
                >
                  <MenuIcon />
                </IconButton>
                <Menu
                  id="menu-appbar"
                  anchorEl={anchorElNav}
                  anchorOrigin={{
                    vertical: "bottom",
                    horizontal: "left",
                  }}
                  keepMounted
                  transformOrigin={{
                    vertical: "top",
                    horizontal: "left",
                  }}
                  open={Boolean(anchorElNav)}
                  onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
                  sx={{
                    display: { xs: "block", md: "none" },
                  }}
                >
                  {context.token && context.userRole === "USER" && (
                    <MenuItem key="submission" onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                      <Typography textAlign="center">Submission</Typography>
                    </MenuItem>
                  )}
                  {context.token && context.userRole === "JUDGE" && (
                    <MenuItem key="submissions" onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                      <Typography textAlign="center">Submissions</Typography>
                    </MenuItem>
                  )}
                  <MenuItem key="conditions" onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                    <Typography textAlign="center">Conditions</Typography>
                  </MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem key="winner" onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                    <Typography textAlign="center">Winner</Typography>
                  </MenuItem>
                </Menu>
              </Box>
              <Typography
                variant="h6"
                noWrap
                component="div"
                sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: "flex", md: "none" } }}
              >
                LOGO
              </Typography>
              <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" } }}>
                {pages.map((page) => (
                  <Button
                    key={page}
                    onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
                    sx={{ my: 2, color: "white", display: "block" }}
                  >
                    {page}
                  </Button>
                ))}
              </Box>

              <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
                <Tooltip title="Open settings">
                  <IconButton onClick={handleOpenUserMenu} sx={{ p: 0 }}>
                    <Avatar
                      alt="Remy Sharp"
                      src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg"
                    />
                  </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
                <Menu
                  sx={{ mt: "45px" }}
                  id="menu-appbar"
                  anchorEl={anchorElUser}
                  anchorOrigin={{
                    vertical: "top",
                    horizontal: "right",
                  }}
                  keepMounted
                  transformOrigin={{
                    vertical: "top",
                    horizontal: "right",
                  }}
                  open={Boolean(anchorElUser)}
                  onClose={handleCloseUserMenu}
                >
                  {settings.map((setting) => (
                    <MenuItem key={setting} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                      <Typography textAlign="center">{setting}</Typography>
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
                </Menu>
              </Box>
            </Toolbar>
          </Container>
        </AppBar>
      )}
    </AuthContext.Consumer>
  );
};

export default ResponsiveAppBar;
```

Comment: Can you share all the possible values for `context.token` and `context.userRole`?

Comment: The token is just a hash number generated from the userID, userRole and email if the login credentials are correct. And the userRole can be "USER", "JUDGE" or "ADMIN".

Comment: So you render logic seems to be fine. The "Submissions" buttons should only be rendered when the there is a token and the userRole is USER or JUGDE.
If they are showing when they shouldn't, you should check what are those vars values at that moment

Comment: First you should split your code in smaller components to be more readable.
What you need is to use useContext and useMemo hooks to solve render issue.
You can follow this solution https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156#issuecomment-474590693

Comment: What would you expect to be rendered, and why ? Difficult to tell where is the problem, since we don't have any use case here, regarding the user, and what he should see

Comment: if `context.token` and `context.userRole` are already arriving to with values to the `return()` I don't think using `useContext` and `useMemo` should make much of a difference with his issue. And "split your code in smaller components" is not something "should" do. Is just a personal preference.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).